# Get same named file from multiple folders in bundle config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration

I'm using a library called tinymce that has plugins with it. Each is in a folder like so `tinymce/plugins/{pluginName}/plugin.js`. There are about 20ish different plugins, but I only want 8 of them. Is there anyway to do that without writing out 8 lines in my bundle just changing out the `pluginName`?

Comment: One way or another you'll have to distinguish between the excluded and the included folders. Either add the included manually or change the folder name of the excluded (append `__` to the folder name, for example) then change the wildcard you're using in the Bundle configuration to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including only the tiny_mce.js file in the bundle?

I used TinyMCE some time ago and in my `BundleConfig.cs` I did only add:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tinymce").Include("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")); //the main api script only
```

With only this configuration I was able to use all the plugins with no issues. Maybe I'm missing something in your particular scenario, though.

Comment: I assumed tinymce needed me to explicitly include the plugins I need. I just looked at their source code and saw that it handles loading all the plugins I define in the init function. This solves the problem, but I was really hoping there was some way to do something like this `tinymce/plugins/{textcolor,image,paste,colorpicker}/plugins.js` or something.